# Support for import in avpr file from avsc schema file

Tags: java, maven, schema, avro

*I have two schema file*

**First is position.avsc**

```
{
"type":"enum", "name": "Position", "namespace": "avro.examples.baseball",
    "symbols": ["P", "C", "B1", "B2", "B3", "SS", "LF", "CF", "RF", "DH"]
}
```

**Second is player.avsc**

```
{
"type":"record", "name":"Player", "namespace": "avro.examples.baseball",
  "fields": [
   {"name": "number", "type": "int"},
   {"name": "first_name", "type": "string"},
   {"name": "last_name", "type": "string"},
   {"name": "position", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "avro.examples.baseball.Position"} }
  ]
}
```

**I can import these schemas in avdl**

```
@namespace("avro.examples.baseball")
protocol Baseball {
   import schema "position.avsc";
   import schema "player.avsc";
}
```

But I want to define above protocol in **json** and import those schemas in protocol file.
This will be helpful for reusability of schema

Answer (score 4):

Avro idl schema can be specified with two type of files

1. avpr
2. avdl

In case of avpr file, we can not import external schema. All required schemas must present in same file.

For avdl , we can import external schemas from avsc file.

I have verified this for [avro 1.7.7](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/idl.html)